# How to get HTTP responseBody using Selenium, CDP, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, devtools, cdp

I am an AQA and testing an app. According to the test, after the button is clicked, I need to get the responseBody returned from the server, like we have in devtools - network tab. I have tried multiple Java and Python code examples found here, tried to transform them to JavaScript, but nothing worked for me. I've been trying smth like this:

```
try {

    const url = 'http://someUrl';

    const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

    const cdpConnection = await driver.createCDPConnection('page');

    await cdpConnection.execute('Network.responseReceived()', response => { 
        // Network.getResponseBody(), etc.
        const res = response.getResponse();
        console.log(res);
    };

await driver.get(url);
await driver.quit();

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to switch to puppeteer / playwright which use cdp instead of webdriver

Comment: @pguardiario We are just using selenium and it also works with cdp, but all the examples I've found are in JAVA and Python, but in JavaScript it works a bit different and has different commands. Maybe someone has experience to work with selenium, cdp and javaScript

Comment: Javascript + Selenium is not popular, and not actively developed which is why I recommended switching. I'm usually the only one to answer questions like this here.

Comment: @pguardiario Thank you very much! Yeah, I understand! Just joined the team with already existing framework and got the task to intercept the responseBody. Got it, man! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, in that case you should ask your team how to do it but it sounds like someone is messing with you. Post the answer here if they give one please.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Network.responseReceived` is an [Event](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-responseReceived). So you have to listen to the `message` from the underlying CDP connection.

```js
wsConnection.on('message', message => {
    let data = JSON.parse(message);
    if (data.method === 'Network.loadingFinished') {
        // ... load response body here
    }
});
```

> I use `Network.loadingFinished` event instead of `Network.responseReceived`, as the response is then completely loaded.

2. The problem is, that the `CDPConnection` class is not properly implemented yet: [CDPConnection.js#L18](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1a73c3f9f37c3f6a424fff92a7f48966c41d3cc0/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/devtools/CDPConnection.js#L18) It doesn't return any promise. This is message-based communication, though it adds the Message ID, to retrieve later the Response Message from the WebSocket, but it doesn't  handle that response message here [webdriver.js#L1239](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1a73c3f9f37c3f6a424fff92a7f48966c41d3cc0/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L1239)

Until it is implemented you can use custom CDPConnection class. Here is the TypeScript implementation.

```
let ID = 0;

type TAwaiter = {
    id: number
    resolve: (value: any) => void
    reject: (reason?: any) => void
};

export class BiDiCDPConnection {

    private requests: Map<number, TAwaiter> = new Map();

    constructor(private wsConnection, private sessionId: string) {
        wsConnection.on('message', this.onMessage.bind(this));
        wsConnection.on('close', this.onClose.bind(this));
        wsConnection.on('error', this.rejectAll.bind(this));
    }

    execute <T = any> (method, params, onMessageSent: (err) => any = null): Promise<T> {

        let message = {
            sessionId: this.sessionId,
            method,
            params,
            id: ++ID,
        };
        let listener = {
            id: message.id,
            resolve: null,
            reject: null,
        };
        let promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
            listener.resolve = resolve;
            listener.reject = reject;
        });

        this.requests.set(listener.id, listener);

        this.wsConnection.send(JSON.stringify(message), onMessageSent)
        return promise;
    }

    private onMessage (message: Buffer) {
        let params = JSON.parse(message.toString());
        let { id, result } = params;

        if (id != null && this.requests.has(id)) {
            this.requests.get(id)?.resolve?.(result);
            this.requests.delete(id);
        }
    }

    private onClose () {
        this.rejectAll(new Error(`CDPConnection: The underlying connection was closed`));
    }

    private rejectAll(error: Error) {

        let awaiters = this.requests.values();
        this.requests = new Map();

        for (let awaiter of awaiters) {
            awaiter.reject(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you initialize the class and use it for your calls, after you create the inner cdp connection, as `createCDPConnection` establishes the WebSocket connection.

```
const cdpConnection = await driver.createCDPConnection('page');
const wsConnection = driver._wsConnection;
const bidiCdpConnection = new BiDiCDPConnection(wsConnection, driver.sessionId);


wsConnection.on('message', message => {
    let data = JSON.parse(message);
    if (data.method === 'Network.loadingFinished') {
                
        let response = await bidiCdpConnection.execute('Network.getResponseBody', {
            requestId: data.params.requestId,
        });
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

---

I use this to monitor ([selenium-query/BrowserNetworkMonitor.ts](https://github.com/tenbits/selenium-query/blob/master/src/webdriver/network/BrowserNetworkMonitor.ts)) and intercept ([selenium-query/BrowserNetworkInterceptor.ts](https://github.com/tenbits/selenium-query/blob/master/src/webdriver/network/BrowserNetworkInterceptor.ts))  requests.  You can take and modify those classes for your initial needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @tenbits! Will have a try!

Answer (score 0):

I am close to getting this to work... but not quite there. See my code here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/issues/1155
If anyone can figure out the last step I'm missing, that'd be so amazing.
ie.

```
let test = await cdpConnection.execute('Fetch.getResponseBody', {
                requestId: obj.params.requestId,
              });
              console.log(test); // ------>  THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED !!!!
```